# Does grep accept `+` as a regex - Better alternative to regex?

Tags: regex, macos, grep

I am trying to use the following syntax with grep

```
 cat Notes.rtf | grep -i  "\(D*\)ters"
```

The result is fine . However when I attempt to use

```
cat Notes.rtf | grep -i  "\(D+\)ters"
```

There is no result.

I came across [this](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html) page and it seems that regex does not support  `+`
Is that correct is there an equivalent to + with grep. IS there a better alternative to grep for max OSX terminal ?

Answer (score 4):

grep doesn't support extended regex properties like `\D` (matching a non-digit) unless your use `-P` flag  (PCRE) or `-E` flag (extended regex) like this:

```
grep -Pi "\D+ters" Notes.rtf
```

OR

```
grep -Ei "\D+ters" Notes.rtf
```

Likewise `+` also need not be escaped while using `P` or `E` flags.